# A particular DE as first order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

When does a differential equation

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+a\frac{dy}{dt}+by=cu(t)+d\frac{du}{dt}$

admit a solution? If $d=0$, the existence is answered by Picard-lindelöf, and we can write it as a system on the form

$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$

where $x$ is a vector by letting $x_1=y$, $x_2=\frac{dy}{dt}$ and so on. When can we do that for the equation above with $d \neq 0$, and how?

Comment: Depends on how nice $u$ is. What is known about $u$?

Answer (score 0):

You can still put this system in state space form.

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1\\\dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-a ~~~ 1 \\-b ~~~ 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}d\\c\end{bmatrix} u$$

You can check that $x_1=y$. This is called observable canonical form. Also this equation always has a unique solution for all initial conditions $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.